# Angular UI - set active tab programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-tabset

I using AngularUI with this code:

```
<uib-tabset type="pills">
    <uib-tab heading="Tab 1">Tab 1 content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Tab 2">Tab 2 content</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

I want to programmatically change the current active tag from my angular-controller code. For example, select tab "2" to be the active.

How this can be done?

Comment: Did you try providing an ID to each tab and then set focus on it?

Comment: I thought about this. Seems to me like a wrong approach, when dealing with AngularJS (maybe good approach for JQuery). I'm wrong?

Comment: have you tried going over the docs ? there's an example that sets a specific tab using an outside button click

Comment: The solution suggested by Ashwani uses index, which is equivalent of giving ID. In both cases, you could generate the ID/Index using Angular's capabilities.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the active property on ui-tabset.
Then You need to have indexes on each tab to work from outside context.

```
<uib-tabset type="pills" active="active">
    <uib-tab heading="Tab 1" index="0">Tab 1 content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Tab 2" index="1">Tab 2 content</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

See this working plnkr:
[Working Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eXSL3j6xKT041ING7hBT?p=preview)

Comment: How can we do it for dynamic tabsets?

Comment: @Sana You mean something like this ?  https://plnkr.co/edit/GQfq8zpKqGm2uZWA8oGU?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420035/setting-active-tab-on-dynamically-created-tabs-with-angular-ui-bootstrap) helped me to figure out.

I used two variables in the scope: `$scope.showTabsInView` and `$scope.activeTabIndex`.

Default Values are:

```
$scope.showTabsInView = false;
$scope.activeTabIndex = 0;
```

First, I loaded my `dynamic tabs`, then I specified the value of `activeTabIndex`. Then I changed the value of `showTabsInView` to true.

```
<uib-tabset ng-if="showTabsInView" active="activeTabIndex">
    <uib-tab data-ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">{{tab.content}}</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

You can simply ignore `dynamic tabs` and `$scope.showTabsInView` if your case is not that much complicated.